# What's the difference between an HTTP Request Message and a Salesforce Rest Resource and the HttpRequest class?

Tags: rest-api, rest

I am new to HTTP and Salesforce's APIs

What is the difference between the salesforce rest resource they talk about in this trailhead module - https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/api_basics/api_basics_rest 
and an HTTP request message?  There's also the HttpRequest.... I am not sure how they  all fit together

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This classifies as a very broad question, but some of these pointers should help.

HTTP, REST, HTTP Messages are all inter-related yet different.

[HTTP is a protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Overview) used to communicate between client and server to fetch resources.

> HTTP is a protocol which allows the fetching of resources, such as HTML documents. It is the foundation of any data exchange on the Web and a client-server protocol, which means requests are initiated by the recipient, usually the Web browser.

[HTTP Message](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Messages) is term used for the *data* exchanged between client and server. [`HttpRequest`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_httprequest.htm) is one such *data* which is sent to the server by a client while making a request, and that [`HttpResponse`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_httpresponse.htm#apex_classes_restful_http_httpresponse) is the other set of *data* which is sent back to the client from the server.

> HTTP messages are how data is exchanged between a server and a client. There are two types of messages: requests sent by the client to trigger an action on the server, and responses, the answer from the server.

A Salesforce REST Resource is a resource exposed as an API (imagine an Apex class annotated with [`@RestResource`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_rest_resource.htm)) which is exposed to return certain data based on certain request based on the HTTP protocol and utilizing the HTTP Messages (HttpRequest/HttpResponse) as the component for data exchange. You can find more on [REST here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/REST).

Comment: this is fantastic! So in this trailhead module - when they say rest resource they do not mean @restresource, they mean it's a http request into Salesforce? https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/api_basics/api_basics_rest

Comment: That's correct. REST resource here refers to the literal meaning of the same. The annotation `@RestResource` will be only required, if you want to code and expose a REST API. Consider how you can call Sobject describe methods, which are already available as a REST (API) Resource provided by Salesforce.

Answer (score 3):

The [REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_what_is_rest_api.htm) is a set of *standard* function calls you can use assuming you have API access. For example, you can use /services/data/v44.0/sobjects/Account to create a new account.

The [RestResource annotation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_rest_resource.htm) allows you to build a *custom* function call you can use for more complicated logic, such as calling /services/apexrest/GetInvoice to get an invoice for an opportunity, using whatever payload (XML, JSON, etc) that you'd like to use.

The [HttpRequest](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_httprequest.htm) class allows Apex classes (Salesforce) to call third-party services. Note that the first two are inbound calls to Salesforce, while the latter is an outbound call from Salesforce to another server.

Answer (score 0):

A `@RestResource` annotated class is used to receive *inbound* requests.

An `HttpRequest` is used to make *outbound* requests.